# Name a column as the current date

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I am using **Teradata SQL Assistant** and I would like to create a column with the name being the  actual **current date** (eg. 19/12/2012).

Comment: Can you update your question with the expected column name with an example?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What purpose would it serve? BTW, I smell some kind of a bad design decision here, but I might be wrong. It occurs to me that whenever separate tables or columns are created for dates/date ranges, it would be much better to solve the problem by a single, properly designed table, and if the amount of data requires it, applying partitioning.

Comment: I need to output a table every day that will show a flow of values for the proceeding 90 days. I basically want to be able to pivot the data I already have stored but have found that I can't do this within teradata, so was going to have to do it manually with case statements which is possible as I will know the finite size of my pivot table.

Answer (score 2):

IF you name your column name like `[Current Date]` with square brackets, it's possible. But please keep away from reserved keywords though.

But on a re-reading note, I believe you are referring to have a name such as `18-Dec-2012` as column name? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes I am referring to the actual date, ie. 18/12/2012 or in any format.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about `teradata`. But the following query gave me the result as desire in `SQL SERVER 2008`

```
declare @sql nvarchar(128) = '
select 
(column_name) as [' + cast(CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) as nvarchar(32)) + ']
from (table_name)'
exec(@sql)
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Prahalad but I can't declare variables in Teradata SQL so this approach will not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments about creating a pivot table, you might want to generate the code needed to create your result set.  I'm doing something similar.  Take a look at the example I posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13895370/1275871).  You might be able to do something similar.

The result set from the query will contain the code used for a "pivot" table.  In my case, the columns are named as the date prefixed with a "D" (like D20121217 for today).  If you want them as actual dates, just change the format and surround the generated column names with double-quotes.  After it runs, just copy the result back to the Query window and execute.