# teradata : to calulate cast as length of column

Tags: teradata

I need to use `cast` function with length of column in teradata.

say I have a table with following data ,

```
id | name
1|dhawal
2|bhaskar
```

I need to use cast operation something like

```
select cast(name as CHAR(<length of column>) from table
```

how can i do that?

thanks
Dhawal

Comment: Does is have to be a fixed length CHAR or is a VARCHAR ok, too?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the length by looking at the table definition - either manually (`show table`) or by writing [dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13896108) that queries `dbc.ColumnsV`.

**update**
You can find the maximum length of the actual data using

```
select max(length(cast(... as varchar(<large enough value>))) from TABLE
```

But if this is for FastExport I think [casting as varchar(large-enough-value)](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Tools/Problem-in-Creating-Delimited-Data-file-using-FastExport/m-p/64648/highlight/true#M9892) and postprocessing to remove the 2-byte length info FastExport includes is a better solution (since exporting a CHAR() will results in a fixed-length output file with lots of spaces in it).

You may know this already, but just in case: Teradata usually recommends switching to TPT instead of the legacy `fexp`.

Comment: I need to write a program in per, that uses fast export to save table data as pipe separated file. so that it can be loaded to some other database.
so need to use cast operation to remove special characters added by fast export. and also need to save file space as well, so need to use cast operation with length of column data

Comment: thanks for the reply ,I can find column length but I need to find length of data in column so can cast to that length.

Comment: Why do you want to use FastExport instead of TPT, which supports Deleimited data out-of-the-box?