# SQL to identify duplicate columns from table having hundreds of column

Tags: sql, teradata

I've 250+ columns in customer table. As per my process, there should be only one row per customer however I've found few customers who are having more than one entry in the table

After running distinct on entire table for that customer it still returns two rows for me. I suspect one of column may be suffixed with space / junk from source tables resulting two rows of same information.

```
select distinct * from ( select  * from customer_table where custoemr = '123' ) a;
```

Above query returns two rows. If you see with naked eye to results there is not difference in any of column.

I can identify which column is causing duplicates if I run query every time for each column with distinct but thinking that would be very manual task for 250+ columns.

This sounds like very dumb question but kind of stuck here. Please suggest if you have any better way to identify this, thank you.

Comment: You could write a dynamic sql script going through all columns of your table and comparing columns for only the customers having more than 1 row in your table.

Comment: Can you simply copy-paste the 2 rows to the post?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?  You have tagged both.

Comment: 250+ columns for a customer table sounds like a real problem. That sounds like there is likely some serious normalization issues.

Comment: @rigerta - never tried that need to work and see about dynamic sql with variable, pls share sample sql that would run on teradata. I'm using teradata sql assist. thanks for your help.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz  - I did that, putting in excel and cross validating with EXACT function in excel all came TRUE and same. As I said this is getting caused by spaces / junk that are not getting copied while putting in excel

Comment: sorry, thought it was sql server :) terradata was just added in the tags! 
simple search took me to this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895370/how-to-execute-dynamic-sql-in-teradata

Comment: @Fred i'm using sql on teradata

Comment: agree with @SeanLange - but my end customer is using some rapid BI platform which works very slow when you put join overhead on that BI reporting application, so trying to create aggregate / summarized table, here.

Comment: Instead of copy-paste, use SQL Assistant export. If you want, you can send me the results by mail.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz thank you that worked!! Tried to use out of box export function rather than copy paste. I could see it, now!! thank you for saving my hour long efforts.

Comment: All, also quick note of caution, when you EXACT function on excel after exporting data. Copy your TRUE / FALSE results to new row using paste special - with only values before you search or find for FALSE values.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this one-time issue with sql is too much effort. Simply copy-paste to excel, transpose data into columns and use some simple function like "if a==b then 1 else 0".